# Trouble with mouse pad after installing/booting up Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bios, mouse, uefi

So I just received on old laptop from a friend and currently trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on the laptop. Here are the specs of the laptop:

Brand: ASUS
Memory: 2.8 GiB
Processor: Intel Pentium(R) CPU P6200 @ 2.13 GHz 
Graphics: Intel Ironlake Mobile 
OS type: 64-bit 
Disk: 1.5 GB

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using the same USB as I'm using right now on a desktop computer of mine I have, but put 16.04 LTS on it instead to go ahead and update. It came with Windows 7 pre-installed on the laptop and went ahead and wiped it out with Ubuntu.

When I tried to install, I've run into several problems:

1) For some reason the only way I can "use" the laptop now is if I boot the live USB in UEFI mode from the BIOS screen. When I tried to boot up in a "non" UEFI mode for some reason it takes me to a GRUB screen which I don't know what to do from there. When I install from the UEFI mode it gives me an option to "force the UEFI installation" which will essentially not let me able to boot up from the BIOS screen any more which I'm a little concerned with because that's the only way I've done it in the past.

2) When I do continue without forcing the UEFI installation it installs Ubuntu on there perfectly fine, but when I get to the home screen my mouse pad isn't recognized at all. Because of this, I can't enable my wifi because I can't click on it to choose which wifi I'm trying to connect too; which also doesn't allow me to install things through the terminal.

Any suggestions on what I could do in this situation would greatly be appreciated!

Edit: Here is what I get for my lsusb and lspci: (for the sake of simplicity I put it in pastebin)

http://pastebin.com/0pyHYnME